# Why is there red colorspace covering the bright white light when everything else shows normally?

Tags: python, color-space

I am trying to figure out why the bright white light gives the red color space from my Basler camera. I want to eliminate the red color space from the white bright lights. Everything else shows normally, except when there is a bright light present. I have attached the pictures here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i6L6ihzgSkE1fb-FYFL8ncFLOloJSUqc/view?usp=sharing

I believe is has to do with line 40-41, but I am not sure how would I modify this code. (package_detection_img = cv2.cvtColor(package_detection_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
package_detection_img = package_detection_img / 255.0).

I appreciate everyone's help! Here is my code:

```
run_camera():        
        converter = pylon.ImageFormatConverter()
        converter.OutputPixelFormat = pylon.PixelType_BGR8packed
        converter.OutputBitAlignment = pylon.OutputBitAlignment_MsbAligned

        top_camera.OutputQueueSize = 2
        top_camera.StartGrabbing(pylon.GrabStrategy_LatestImages)

        try:
            while (True):
                top_grabResult = top_camera.RetrieveResult(5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_Return)
                while not top_grabResult.GrabSucceeded():
                    logger.info("top grab failed, trying again")
                    top_grabResult = top_camera.RetrieveResult(5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_Return)

                if top_grabResult.GrabSucceeded():
                    image = converter.Convert(top_grabResult)
                    package_detection_img = image.Array
                    package_detection_img = cv2.rotate(package_detection_img, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

                    # Get the original camera resolution
                    original_h, original_w = package_detection_img.shape[:2]
                    # print(f"Current camera resolution: {original_w} x {original_h}")

                    # Define the desired size as per your original image shape
                    desired_h, desired_w = 1088, 720
                    left = 623
                    right = desired_w - left

                    # Adjusted cropping
                    cropped_width = original_w - (left + right)

                    package_detection_img = package_detection_img[:, left:left + cropped_width]

                    # Resize to desired size (original training image size)
                    package_detection_img = cv2.resize(package_detection_img, (desired_w, desired_h))
                    cv2.imshow('Live Stream', package_detection_img)  # display the window with the name 'Live Stream'
                    cv2.waitKey(1)

                    # Adjusted for brand_name_img
                    brand_name_desired_w = 108.5
                    brand_name_desired_h = 519.5
                    brand_name_crop_w = int((desired_w - brand_name_desired_w) / 2)
                    brand_name_crop_h = int((desired_h - brand_name_desired_h) / 2)
                    brand_name_img = package_detection_img[brand_name_crop_h:-brand_name_crop_h,
                                     brand_name_crop_w:-brand_name_crop_w]
                    brand_name_img = cv2.resize(brand_name_img, (int(brand_name_desired_w), int(brand_name_desired_h)))

                    # Call letterbox here, before the color conversion and normalization
                    package_detection_img = letterbox(package_detection_img, new_shape=(desired_h, desired_w))[0]
                    package_detection_img = cv2.cvtColor(package_detection_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    package_detection_img = package_detection_img / 255.0
                    # cv2.imshow('Live Stream', package_detection_img)  # display the window with the name 'Live Stream'
                    # cv2.waitKey(1)


                    # Call transformations here for both package and brand images
                    # Convert numpy arrays to PIL images for transformations
                    package_detection_img = Image.fromarray((package_detection_img * 255).astype(np.uint8))
                    brand_name_img = Image.fromarray((brand_name_img * 255).astype(np.uint8))

                    yield package_detection_img, brand_name_img

                else:
                    logger.info(f"Top camera failed to grab an image")
                    yield np.zeros((desired_h, desired_w, 3))

        finally:
            top_camera.Close()

detect():
    if source == '1':
        for batch in dataloader:
            # print("Dataloader successfully incorporated")

            # Unnormalize before displaying
            batch = unnormalize(batch)

            frame = batch[0].squeeze(0).permute(1, 2, 0).cpu().numpy()  # Convert back to HWC format for OpenCV

            # Convert back to 0-255 range and to uint8 for OpenCV
            frame = (frame * 255).astype(np.uint8)

            # Keep a copy of the frame for display purposes
            frame_img = frame.copy()

            # Resize, convert to RGB, normalize, and convert to tensor for inference
            img = cv2.resize(frame, (int(imgsz[1].item()), int(imgsz[0])))
            img = img / 255.0
            img = np.ascontiguousarray(img.transpose((2, 0, 1)))  # HWC to CHW
            img = torch.from_numpy(img).float().unsqueeze(0).to(device)


            print(f"Transformed img shape: {img.shape}")
```

Comment: My guess is that a pixel is encoded as an integer in the form `b*65536+g*256+r`. By using `/255`, you're treating the pixel as an integer rather than an encoded color. The division eliminates the blue. (My specific encoding formula may be wrong but the principle remains. There are other encodings that amount to the same thing and would better result in what you're seeing.)

Comment: @Ouroborus Thank you for your output! I am new to the colorspace concept. In this case, how would I change the pixels from integer to encoded color?